# como crear una vista en sql server?

Tags: sql

Quiero realizar una vista en sqlserver. Pero me marca error cuando intento eliminar una tabla si es que existe. Las tablas que estoy creado no son temporales.

Este el Query que estoy realizando:

```
 create view SP_VDebugEfficiency1
 as

 --Borramos las tablas is estas existen
 drop table if exists vDebug
 drop table if exists vEfficiency

 --Creamos las tablas
 create table vDebug
 (
  ID int,
  UnitID varchar(50),
  Stid int,
  CreationTime varchar(50),
  Description varchar(50),
  TestResult varchar(30),
  LooperCount int
 )

 create table vEfficiency
 (
  ID1 int,
  Stid int,
  CreationTime1 varchar(50),
  StationType1 varchar(50),
  LooperCount1 int,
  TestResult1 varchar(30),
  UnitID1 varchar(50),
  ID2 int,
  CreationTime2 varchar(50),
  StationType2 varchar(50),
  LooperCount2 int,
  TestResult2 varchar(30),
  UnitID2 varchar(50)
 )
```

Al ejecutar el Query me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: Error]

Comment: La vista se crea sobre tablas ya existentes. No haces DDL en la definición de una vista.

Comment: @Alfabravo que significa DDL?

Comment: **DDL** = data definition language. O sea, CREATE, DROP, ALTER. **DML** = Data modification, o sea INSERT, SELECT, DELETE, UPDATE.

Comment: @Alfabravo entonces no se puede crear ningun tipo  de tabla en una vista?

Comment: Una tabla común y corriente, no. Para qué crear una tabla en una vista? Una vista es una proyección de datos de una o varias tablas. Simplificas el acceso (y la optimización) del acceso a una consulta sobre una o varias tablas que ya existen. Entonces, ¿para qué necesitas crear una tabla? QUé buscas?

Comment: @Alfabravo. Agrupa tus comentarios y los dejas en la respuesta. Son acertados y cualquier otra persona que lea esta pregunta puede salir más que con un "no se puede".

Comment: @Alfabravo lo que busco es obtener los datos de otras tablas ya existente. Si no inserto los datos a estas tablas el query dura el quintuple que haciendolo asi como es que quiero. no agregue mas quuery porque es muy extenso.

Comment: Te sugiero reescribir tu pregunta, incluir unos datos de prueba y las tablas sobre las que estás consultando. Luego, dejar este intento de vista que ya dijimos que no va a servir (es lo que has intentado) y luego nos dices cuál es el resultado esperado. No logro entender bien qué buscas o en qué query duras el quíntuple y ese es el problema real en el que podemos ayudarte